# How to get second last record in a queryset in Django?

Tags: django

I have a model named `employees_salary` and I need to get second highest salary of employee.

I know that I can filter `latest()`, `first()`, `last()`** and these are working, but how to filter second last? Am I missing something?

Comment: The question title does not justify the accepted answer. You must add second highest salary as stated by @Naresh in comment section instead of second last record .

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use order_by with a reverse filter (-) and then grab the second object by using [1].

```
class Salaries(models.Model):

  employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  salary = models.IntegerField()


q = Salaries.objects.all().order_by('-salary')

second_highest_paid_name = q[1].employee_name
```

Comment: user "q = Salaries.objects.all().order_by('-salary)[1]" .. it will give you second highest salary record..

Comment: what if the first and second salary is same??? as per you code it will give only highest salary.. not the second highest.

Answer (score 5):

This way will also work

```
class EmployeeSalary(models.Model):    
    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    salary = models.IntegerField()

#code for view
q = EmployeeSalary.objects.all().order_by('-salary')[1:1]
second_paid_name = q[0].employee_name
second_paid_salary = q[0].salary
```

Comment: This solution is better because it returns an empty queryset instead of raising an exception if there is no second record. Just an important note: it should be a `[1:2].first()` for getting the first result. At least in my tests with `[1:1]` the result was always None.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work, if you try it like this:

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):   
    title = models.CharField()
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py:

```
def postlist(request):
    latest_post = Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[0]
    secondlast_post =  Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[1]
    context = {
         'latest_post' : latest_post, 'secondlast_post' : secondlast_post ,
    }
    return render(request, 'yourtemplate.html', context)
```