# How to get penultimate item from QuerySet in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

How to get the penultimate item from **Django** **QuerySet**? I tried `my_queryset[-2]` (after checking whether the `my_queryset` length is greater than 1) as follows:

```
if len(my_queryset)>1:
     query = my_queryset[-2]
```

and it returns:

> Exception Value:   Negative indexing is not supported.

Is there some "Django" way to get such item?

The only thing which comes to my mind is to reverse the queryset and get `my_queryset[2]` but I'm not sure about its efficiency.

**EDIT:**

```
scans = self.scans.all().order_by('datetime')
if len(scans)>1:
    scan = scans[-2]
```

Comment: which item do you want to get? If you could tell us the logic on which the queryset is built, it would provide better understanding of what you want and also help us help you.

Comment: I've edited the answer and added a code at the bottom. The only thing I want is not to get last item but item before last.

Comment: Please check this post: [Django- How to get second last record in a queryset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307405/django-how-to-get-second-last-record-in-a-queryset). As for the ordering it doesn't have any effect on efficiency if you sort in descending.

Comment: Reversing the queryset is no more a performance issue than sorting it in the original order - as long as you have an index on the sort column (or the dataset is small enough) it is fast in either direction.

Comment: Note that `len(my_queryset)` will cause Django to load the entire queryset. This might be very slow for larger queryset, so you could use `my_queryset.count()` instead. Alternatively, don't use `count()` or `len()` at all, try to fetch `scans[x]`, then catch the possible `IndexError`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code which produces an error

```
scans = self.scans.all().order_by('datetime')
if len(scans)>1:
    scan = scans[-2]
```

Is the equivalent of

```
scans = self.scans.all().order_by('-datetime')
if len(scans)>1:
    scan = scans[1]
```

If you want to get the second one the index to use is `1` and not `2` because in python offsets starts from `0`.

Also note that [django querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) which means you can change your mind about ordering without a performance hit provided that proper indexes are available.

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve
>   any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long,
>   and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is
>   evaluated. Take a look at this example: